# pupil detection using opencv, with infrared image

Tags: image, opencv, infrared, eye-detection

I am trying the detect the pupil from a infrared image and calculate the center of the pupil. 
In my setup, i used a camera sensitive to infrared light, and I added a visible light filter to the lens and two infrared LED around the camera. 
However, the image I got is blur not so clear, maybe this caused by the low resolution of the camera, whose max is about 700x500.

In the processing, the first thing i did was to convert this RGB image to gray image, how ever the result is terrible. and it got nothing in the results.

[image] [image]

```
int main()
{
    //load image
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("11_13_2013_15_36_09.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("original");
    cv::imshow("original", src);
    cv::waitKey(10);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "failed to find the image";
        return -1;
    }

    // Invert the source image and convert to graysacle
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(~src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::imshow("image1", gray);
    cv::waitKey(10);

    // Convert to binary image by thresholding it
    cv::threshold(gray, gray, 220, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::imshow("image2", gray);
    cv::waitKey(10);

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>contours;
    cv::findContours(gray.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Fill holes in each contour
    cv::drawContours(gray, contours, -1, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), -1);
    cv::imshow("image3", gray);
    cv::waitKey(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
        int radius = rect.width / 2;

        // If controu is big enough and has round shape
        // Then it is the pupil
        if (area >= 800 &&
            std::abs(1 - ((double)rect.width / (double)rect.height)) <= 0.3 &&
            std::abs(1 - (area / (CV_PI * std::pow(radius, 2)))) <= 0.3)
        {
            cv::circle(src, cv::Point(rect.x + radius, rect.y + radius), radius, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2);
        }
    }
    cv::imshow("image", src);
    cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

When the original image was converted, the gray image is terrible, does anyone know a better solution to this? I am completely new to this. for the rest of the code for finding the circle, if you have any comments, just tell me. and also i need to extra the position of the two glint (the light point) on the original image, does anyone has some idea?
thanks.

Comment: You might want to describe why the grey picture is bad and which part of your code do you think is responsible for that.

Comment: that is also what i am trying to find, I simple used this cv::cvtColor(~src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY), to convert the BGR image to GRAY image. then the image is too light to distinguish the pupil with other parts. to carry on other processing, this conversion is the first step. what should I do with it, instead of converting the color image to gray image? see the link for how the image looks like before and after.

Comment: I have to log in to see you image, which I and many others won't do.

Comment: thank you Mark for letting me know this. I thought you can directly open the link and see the image. the starOverflow does not allow me to post image here. so I have to post it somewhere else. if that link also does work, i do not know what to do next. :-(

Comment: Instead of converting to GRAY, I would suggest you to go into HSV (it gives much better description of colors and you won't lose any information from RGB-Gray conversion).. Also, try to use lossless formats as suggested by @David (for example, PNG)..

In a recent eye-tracking project, I used ellipse fitting since I wanted to track the Iris as well as the pupil to give a better estimate of the center. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try equalizing and filtering your source image before thresholding it ;)